# keep getting kicked out my google login when using chrome.identity api

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-drive-api

I'm creating a chrome extension, I want to connect it with google spreadsheet to modify and load sheets.
When I using [chrome.identity](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/identity) API to get auth, my session of google account in Chrome always been kick out. even when I using sample code from the [google](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/app_identity).

here is some code of my extension(only paste the core code):
manifest:

```
"permissions": [ "*://*/*",
                "storage",
                "tabs",
                "contextMenus",
                "alarms",
                "identity"],

"oauth2": {
    "client_id": "64262386828-sng3chvgvldosl1586trtngrcp7ocfv5.apps.googleusercontent.com",
    "scopes": [
        "https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",
        "https://docs.google.com/feeds",
        "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"
    ]
},

"browser_action": {
         "default_popup": "popup.html"
}
```

popup.js:

```
var ci = chrome.identity;
```

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#getAuth").click(function () {
        getAuth();
    });

```
function getAuth() {
    var access_token;
    var retry = true;
    getToken();
    function getToken() {
        ci.getAuthToken({ interactive: true }, function(token) {
            if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                console.log(chrome.runtime.lastError);
                return;
            }
            access_token = token;
        });
    }

}
```

});

Here is a short video to show this problem:
http://screencast.com/t/yiKYJUBv
and also, it only kicks me out from chrome, I can still access Gmail or something else.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you don't have another Google account (like another email account) open at the same time?  Even opening Google Docs in a web page normally, will cause goofs if you have more than one account open.  That is, not logged out.

Comment: Thank you, I'm very sure that I have only one Google account in current chrome, actually I always use only one Google account, I uploaded a video to show it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its because the client_id doesnt match the extension id.
The error only happens in a extension loaded manually (it has different id than the store one).
Solution: create a second clientid in the dev console, pointing to your local extension. Use that one while developing. Switch it back before publishing (very important!)